# Seemantham Putran or Putri, according to our scriptures/references

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, advaita, vaishnavism

Seemantham Putran or Semmantham Putri?

Can someone tell me which is given more preference according to our scriptures?

Can someone tell me the things mentioned about baby boy and baby girl according to our scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

First born boy or baby is generally known as 'seemantha putran' or 'seemantha putri'.  Seemanta is one of the `samskara` done, generally during 7th or 8th month of pregnancy.

There is *no* preference in general. However, since the lineage has to continue for many generations, at least one boy child was desired by dharmic parents. But there is no necessity to be biased, there is no base for it in scriptures.

Different samskaras are defined [upanayana etc] for the boy as he ages, and similarly for the girl child.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Much appreciate it!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).